# jqGrid. Grand Total with million rows from a REST

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-php

How to show Grand Total with million rows from a REST?

[Documentation](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/grouping/summary_and_grand_total/index.html) has the example when all data is loading once with option `loadonce: true` but that is a very small number of rows. How can I attain the same with partial data loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the total of the column field on the server and transport it using userdata again with options userDataOnFooter

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    ...
    footer : true,
    userDataOnFooter: true,
...
});
```

See the docs for these options and the [demo here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/functionality/customize_footer/index.html)